# table_editors-moc.ads not found

Tags: qt, ada

I'm using gcc (GCC) 4.5.4 20120510 for GNAT GPL 2012 (20120509)
and qtada from qtada-gpl-3.2.0-20120708-3871-qt4.8.2-2.exe installer.
I'm trying to compile example from "..\GNAT\2012\examples\qtada\sql\cached_table", but it say "`table_editors-moc.ads not found`",

The error came from statement :

```
with Table_Editors.MOC; pragma Warnings (Off, Table_Editors.MOC);
--  Child package MOC must be included in the executable.
```

Where can i found the "Child package MOC" that contains "table_editors-moc.ads" and another moc file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Qt or QtAda, but a quick search indicates that Qt uses a Meta Object Compiler (MOC) to auto-generate source code from macros. Could it be that your Table_Editor.MOC is supposed to be generated?

Comment: I think you're right; `Makefile.am` shows them being generated. So maybe something went wrong during `configure`?

Comment: thank you egilhh, yes you are right, MOC is auto generated, it might be my mistake when installing qt, some file is missing in the example folder, i have to create file chached_table_moc.gpr manually, and after some clean and build, the example work fine

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that QtAda has installed its examples at `\GNAT\2012\examples`; judging by the way GNAT is set up on this Mac, I'd have expected `\GNAT\2012\share\examples`.

However .. I suspect that QtAda's file system layout is complicated enough that you'll need to use a "[GNAT Project file](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html)" to do the build. I hope there's a `.gpr` file in the same directory as your example code (if not, I can't help); if so, and assuming it's called `cached_table.gpr`, then in a command window say

```
gnatmake -p -P cached_table.gpr
```

or  (following the [documentation for QtAda 3.1](http://www.qtada.com/documentation/qtada-3.1.0/qtada_ugr/integration-gnat.html))

```
gprbuild -p -P cached_table.gpr
```

Comment: thank you simon, but after visiting some web, i create folder called "gpr" and chached_table_moc.gpr manually in it, then everything work fine, yes it might be something wrong during installation process.